# request json data and save it to the database

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic

This has been driving me nuts for the past 2 hours, hopefully someone will have an answer.
I need to request a data from another website using Querystrings.
The response is in one line JSON format and I will need to save it to my database. 
How can I do it?
I tried it the following way but it did not work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: { client_id: "xxx", client_secret: "xxx", grant_type: "authorization_code", redirect_uri: "http://www.xxx.com/savetodb.asp", CODE: "<%=Request.QueryString("CODE")%>",
                url: "https://xyz.com/access_token", 
        success: function(output) { 
        $("#result").html(output);
        $("#result").css("display", "block");
        }
        }); 
    });

</script>  

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use GET Requests and send json data. The data parameter option you have doesn't make sense, since the bracket isn't closed. You must use a "Post" request. IF you are just trying to get data, use the url with query string ex) http://www.test.com?q1=key1&q2=key2 and then the function syntax is. Use fiddler to determine what the url is of the actual ajax request and make sure that's correct.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Combined to do post then get, its probably better to use separate functions but this will work for th e demo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function (data) {
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {

                }
           });
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to first post data and get what comes as a response to what I posted.

Comment: So do you suggest it like this? 
url: "https://xyz.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=abcd&client_secret=efgh&grant_type=editor&redirect_uri=http://www.mysite.com/getdata.asp&code=1343546",

Comment: if you need to make multiple requests, combine ajax...see edits above

Comment: sorry where is the code giving error, perhaps syntax I will try to test later

Comment: ahh you probably need to update your urls, in the URL parameter field and also you need to set the data to send. see the jquery api here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

see - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/